# swiftでバイナリファイルの読み書きを行いたい

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

お世話になります。

まだswiftでバイナリファイルを解析（その後オブジェクト化）、
また、バイナリ（オブジェクト）出力を行いたいのですが、

テキストファイルの読み込みなどは、よく見かけるのですが、
バイナリファイルとなると見つかりません。

ipad開発を始めたばかりで、検索するキーワードも思いつきません。

品となるものでも結構ですので、教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

データをバイナリで取り扱うには、`NSData`クラス、Swift3では、`Data`構造体が用意されています。バイト列（UInt8のコレクション）としてバッファを取り扱います。

[API Reference - Foundation - NSData](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata)
[API Reference - Foundation - Data](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data)

ファイルの読み書き、バイト列に対する走査、検索、抽出、挿入、置換、そしてC言語のポインタへの変換など、ひととおりのメソッド、プロパティが用意されているので、リファレンスを一読されることをお勧めします。

以下は、たいしたサンプルコードではありませんが、ファイルをバイナリデータとして開いていることを、実感できるものとして、作ったものです。（Swift3）

```
// デスクトップにあるPNGファイルへのURLを取得。
let dataURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/users/username/Desktop/sprite1.png")
do {
    // ファイル読み込み
    let binaryData = try Data(contentsOf: dataURL, options: [])
    // 先頭から1024バイトを抽出。
    let kbData = binaryData.subdata(in: 0..<1024)
    // 各バイトを16進数の文字列に変換。
    let stringArray = kbData.map{String(format: "%02X", $0)}
    // ハイフォンで16進数を結合する。
    let binaryString = stringArray.joined(separator: "-")
    print(binaryString)
} catch {
    print("Failed to read the file.")
}
```

出力例：

> 89-50-4E-47-0D-0A-1A-0A-00-00-00-0D-49-48-44-52-00-00-00-24-00-00-00-24-08-06-00-00-00-（後略）